# Deploy Error for PHP Google App Engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I have basic HTML website that is being built.  It runs find on the app engine, but when I am trying to deploy the code I get the following error.  I know very little about Python, but I tried to make all my install paths short and without spaces.

- Python installed to "C:\Python27"
- GoogleApp installed to "C:\google_appengine"
- PHP/HTML app located at "C:\temp\movieweb"

I have NOT modified any of the PY code.  All I have done is configure the app.yaml and my website specific stuff. Please help.  It looks like it is all Python related which I have not touched.

> 2013-12-12 11:38:21 Running command: "['C:\Python27\python.exe', '-u', 'C:\google_appengine\appcfg.py', '--no_cookies', u'--email=myemail@gmail.com', '--passin', 'update', 'C:\temp\movieweb']"
>
> 11:38 AM Application: movieweb-j2s2; version: 1
>   11:38 AM Host: appengine.google.com
>   11:38 AM Starting update of app: movieweb-j2s2, version: 1
>   11:38 AM Getting current resource limits.
>   Password for myemail@gmail.com: 11:38 AM Scanning files on local disk.
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 196, in 
>   run_file(**file**, globals())
>   File "C:\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 192, in run_file
>   execfile(script_path, globals_)
>   File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4810, in 
>   main(sys.argv)
>   File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4801, in main
>   result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
>   File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2611, in Run
>   self.action(self)
>   File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4495, in **call**
>   return method()
>   File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3378, in Update
>   self._UpdateWithParsedAppYaml(appyaml, self.basepath, yaml_file_basename)
>   File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3413, in _UpdateWithParsedAppYaml
>   self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, basepath, appyaml, yaml_file_basename)
>   File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3312, in UpdateVersion
>   return appversion.DoUpload(paths, openfunc)
>   File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2144, in DoUpload
>   file_classification = FileClassification(self.config, path)
>   File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 252, in **init**
>   self.__static_mime_type = self.__GetMimeTypeIfStaticFile(config, filename)
>   File "C:\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 282, in __GetMimeTypeIfStaticFile
>   if re.match(regex, filename):
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 137, in match
>   return _compile(pattern, flags).match(string)
>   File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 242, in _compile
>   raise error, v # invalid expression
>   sre_constants.error: unbalanced parenthesis
>   2013-12-12 11:38:23 (Process exited with code 1)

Comment: Finally after dumping the "filename" it was choking on the app.yaml.  I noticed then that in my app.yaml there were \es in the path for the upload: portion of the handlers.  swapped them to be /es and all is well.

Comment: Perhaps post edit as answer and accept the answer for better readability and workflow.